# Play Framework: could not bind from form

Tags: java, forms, scala, view, playframework

I'm developing a play 2.2.3 application and I have some problems to bind the form to my model class.
This is my model class:

```
package models;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Date birthdate;
    private String gender;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // some getter and setters...

}
```

My form:

```
@(form: Form[User])

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.register) {
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Persönliche Daten</legend>
                    @helper.inputText(form("firstname"),'_label -> "Vorname:")
                    @helper.inputText(form("lastname"),'_label -> "Nachname:")
                    @helper.inputDate(form("birthdate"),'_label -> "Geburtstag:")
                    @helper.inputRadioGroup(form("gender"),options = Seq(("male"->"Männlich"),("female"->"Weiblich")),'_label -> "Geschlecht:")
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Login Daten</legend>
                    @helper.inputText(form("username"),'_label -> "Benutzername*:")
                    @helper.inputText(form("password"),'_label -> "Passwort*:")
                    <input id="registersubmit" type="submit" value="Registrieren" accesskey="s"/>
                    <p id="requiredhint">Mit "*" gekennzeichnete Felder sind Pflichtfelder</p>
                </fieldset>
            }
```

And my action method:

```
@Transactional
    public static Result register() {
        Form<User> form = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (form.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest("/registration");
        } else {
            User user = form.get();
            //JPA.em().persist(user);
            System.out.println("User "+user.getUsername()+" successfully saved!");
            return redirect("/index");
        }
    }
```

The fields are in the form, but they are afterwards not binded to the User and null is printed for user.getUsername().
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David, you were in the right direction. As I am mixing languages in the development phase, I had wrong names for the setters, which I would not think will be critical, but it was. So changing for example

```
public String getBenutzername() {
    return username;
}
```

to

```
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be fine. Can you put fields as public and remove getters and setters? Just to check if there is a problem with them or put the complete User class in the example.

Comment: Sorry @user3580294, I can't add a comment without a 50 reputation.

Comment: Ah I see. Reviewing, didn't know that. My apologies.